# What is the difference between scrapy and beautiful soup

Tags: web-scraping

I have read that scrapy is a web crawling tool and beautiful soup is a library of scrapy. But my friend says that both are different and we can achieve the same task in beautifulsoup which is achieved by scrapy. does my friend's point true? I also have the doubt that beautifulsoup is a part of scrapy or it is a different one? please advise me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beautiful soup is a library for HTML parsing and manipulation. It takes in *one* HTML document and allows you to navigate it and manipulate it with simple function calls.

Scrapy is a tool for managing downloads. It takes a URL, downloads the data at this URL, possibly parses this HTML (using any way you want, you can use beautiful soup for that), queues up more URLs to download and manages several downloaders in parallel.

Scrapy is the tool that manages *downloading* of many HTML documents in parallel, beautiful soup is a tool that *parses* one HTML document and can do interesting things with its content. You'll probably use both in combination for the task of *crawling* sites.

Comment: can we use BS in scrapy? scrapy also having access the content of a website right?

Comment: Again, yes, you can use BS in scrapy for *processing* the downloaded HTML. See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html. This shows an example using scrapy's XPATH expressions to parse HTML. But you could just as easily replace that code with BS to parse HTML instead.

Comment: Thanks...nice explanation. clearly said. But can you provide me a good tutorial link explains scrapy, Bs and both

Comment: No, I can't. Learn BS from its documentation, learn scrapy from its documentation, learn from the scrapy documentation at which point you have to parse HTML and put your BS code there.

Comment: i want to know more thing. scrapy can also scrap the content using selectors(xpath and css). you said BS can also scrap the content. then what is the diff between by using selectors to scrap the data and using BS to scrap the data?

Comment: XPATH expressions, just as CSS selectors, are pretty strict. They either apply or they don't. If you need to parse very straight forward HTML, they're a great terse way to parse it. Beautiful soup allows you more programatic access to the HTML's structure; e.g. find the first `<tr>`, then traverse the following three `<td>`, then *if* there's another `<td>` following it, do this that or the other thing. You may need that if the HTML you need to process is less than straight forward and/or dynamic.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Now am clear on my way...thanks for showing me path..:)